# Помогите написать корректный SQL запрос для вывода данных

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть 3 таблицы: users, articles и likes.

Их структуры такие:

- users: id, ...
- articles: id, author_id, ...
- likes: article_id, user_id, liked

Мне нужно написать SQL запрос для получения всех статей определенного `author_id` с пометкой тех, которые пользователь с id X лайкнул. То есть в ответе должны быть данные о **ВСЕХ** статьях автора `author_id` и поле `liked` которое будет = 1 (если пользователь с id X эту статью лайкнул) и 0 (если не лайкнул).

Я пытался делать так:

```
SELECT 
  articles.id, articles.title, likes.liked 
FROM articles LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.user_id = X AND likes.article_id = articles.id 
WHERE articles.author_id = Y
```

но мне выдается ерунда, которая никакого отношения к тому что мне надо не имеет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью подзапроса определяем количество лайков.

```
SELECT 
  a.id, a.title, 
  (SELECT 
     count(*) 
   FROM likes l 
   WHERE l.user_id = <пользователь_X>
   and   l.article_id = a.id) liked_cnt 
FROM articles a
WHERE a.author_id = <определенный_автор>
```

`<пользователь_X>` и `<определенный_автор>` заменить на требуемые значения.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Работает как надо.

Comment: А для чего подзапрос? Почему count не сделать в основном

Comment: Чтобы группировки не было.